# Commutation of currents in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator, correlation-functions, ward-identity

In an outline of a proof of the Ward identities in QED, the authors Green, Schwarz, and Witten in their book "Superstring theory", vol. I, Section 1.5.1,
claim that in the QED the electromagnetic currents $J^\mu(x)$ and $J^\nu(y)$ commute. (Probably they mean that equal time commutators vanish; that would be sufficient to prove the Ward identities.)

I failed to prove the above statement (although I am familiar with another, perturbative, proof of the Ward identities).

**I would be very interested to see a proof of the statement.**

Answer (score 0):

Of course they mean equal time commutators, since only they appear when calculating the derivative of chronological ordering in Green functions. More precisely, the only thing you need when deriving the Ward identity is rather an equal time commutator of the charge density operator $J^{0}(\mathbf x , t)$ with some operator $O(\mathbf y , t)$.

One should combine the explicit expression for the commutator with canonical anticommutation relations for fermion fields,
$$
\{\psi_{i}^{\dagger}(\mathbf x,t),\psi_{j}(\mathbf y,t)\} = \delta_{ij}\delta (\mathbf x- \mathbf y)
$$
i.e., to rewrite commutator through anticommutator. The expression for currents commutator then follows straightforwardly. However, you shouldn't expect that the commutator of two currents is zero.